# Как реализовать функцию, которая смещает разряды влево, и при вытеснении восстанавливает их в правой части?

Tags: c++, c

Как написать функцию, которая смещает разряды влево, и при вытеснении восстанавливает их в правой части; в двоичной системе?

`int num` - число,

`unsigned int pos` - число смещений

Comment: Система счисления какая?

Comment: если для двоичной, то это называется циклический сдвиг, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автор ни чего не сделал для решение вопроса.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Вот это решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/776523):

```
#include <stdint.h>   // for uint32_t
#include <limits.h>   // for CHAR_BIT
// #define NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>

uint32_t rotl32 (uint32_t n, unsigned int c)
{
  const unsigned int mask = (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(n)-1);

  assert ( (c<=mask) &&"rotate by type width or more");
  c &= mask;  // avoid undef behaviour with NDEBUG.  0 overhead for most types / compilers
  return (n<<c) | (n>>( (-c)&mask ));
}

uint32_t rotr32 (uint32_t n, unsigned int c)
{
  const unsigned int mask = (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(n)-1);

  assert ( (c<=mask) &&"rotate by type width or more");
  c &= mask;  // avoid undef behaviour with NDEBUG.  0 overhead for most types / compilers
  return (n>>c) | (n<<( (-c)&mask ));
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что если завернуть это правильное решение в макросы, то в `sizeof(n)` будет гораздо гармоничнее смотреться.

Comment: Кроме появления кучи скобок, макросы ничего интересного в это решение не привнесут.

Comment: почему же, можно будет не писать rotr8, rotr16, rotr32 итп.

Comment: Тут можно уйти в две крайности метапрограммирования - либо в шаблоны, да с фичами C++11 вроде constexpr (впрочем, автор отказывается от C++), либо в макросы. Однако для решения поставленной задачи это излишне. Но вы безусловно правы, универсальный вариант - штука хорошая.

Comment: На мой вкус (с учетом `c &= mask`) assert тут вообще не нужен (просто проверки лучше делать по месту получения внешних данных, а не в подобных функциях).

Comment: @avp assert тут как раз на своем месте стоит - ловит криворукого программиста за руку. А в релизе он магически испарится.

Comment: Ещё один + к макросам: зачастую, не для всех платформ, конструкция подобная этой `y = ( y << n ) | ( y >> ( digits - n ) );` компилируется в одну инструкцию процессора, а например в криптографии таких инструкций очень много выполняется.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>

template <typename T>
T rotate_left( T value, unsigned int bits ) {
    bits &= sizeof( T ) * CHAR_BIT - 1;
    return value << bits | value >> (sizeof( T ) * CHAR_BIT - bits);
}

int rotate_left_c( int value, unsigned int bits ) {
    bits &= sizeof( int ) * CHAR_BIT - 1;
    return value << bits | value >> (sizeof( int ) * CHAR_BIT - bits);
}

int main() {

    int num = 0b11;
    int pos = 257;
    std::cout << std::bitset<sizeof( num ) * CHAR_BIT>( rotate_left  ( num, pos ) ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::bitset<sizeof( num ) * CHAR_BIT>( rotate_left_c( num, pos ) ) << std::endl;
}
```

Сам пример требует стандарта C++14. Шаблонная функция rotate_left сработает в любом стандарте С++.

Comment: `sizeof( T ) * 8 ` - Существуют аппаратные платформы на которых char - 16 бит.

Comment: А на си можно примерчик?

Comment: Добавил функцию для Си

Comment: @dsnk как размер типа char в данном случае влияет на результат?

Comment: @Антон Сазонов - если не ошибаюсь sizeof - возвращает размерность в char-ах?

Comment: @dsnk, оператор sizeof возвращает размер в байтах.

Comment: @Антон Сазонов Просто для примера: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4s7x1k91%28v=vs.120%29.aspx `Возвращает размер своего операнда относительно размера типа char.`

Comment: @dsnk, текущий стандарт языка C++ не двусмысленно говорит о том, что sizeof(char) == sizeof(signed char) == sizeof(unsigned char) == 1. Почитайте первый пункт раздела 5.3.3.

Comment: sizeof **всегда** возвращает размер в `char`. Поэтому для перевода в биты нужно умножать на константу `CHAR_BIT`, которая определена в `limits.h`

Answer (score 4):

Функция может быть написана по-разному. Например, в C++ вы можете использовать следующую функцию:

```
int bits_rotate( int x, unsigned int n )
{
    const unsigned int bit = 1 << ( std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits - 1 );

    n %= std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits;
    unsigned int y = static_cast<int>( x );

    while ( n-- )
    {
        y = ( y << 1 ) | ( ( y & bit ) != 0 );
    }        

    return y;
}
```

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

int bits_rotate( int x, unsigned int n )
{
    const unsigned int bit = 1 << ( std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits - 1 );

    n %= std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits;
    unsigned int y = static_cast<int>( x );

    while ( n-- )
    {
        y = ( y << 1 ) | ( ( y & bit ) != 0 );
    }        

    return y;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;

    for ( unsigned int n = 0; n < 2 * std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits; n++ )
    {        
        std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>( bits_rotate( x, n ) ) << std::endl;
    }           
}
```

Вывод на консоль следующий:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
1048576
2097152
4194304
8388608
16777216
33554432
67108864
134217728
268435456
536870912
1073741824
2147483648
1
2
4
8
16
```

и т.д.

Как указал **@dsnk** функцию можно было бы написать без цикла `while`. Например

```
int bits_rotate( int x, unsigned int n )
{
    const int digits = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits;

    n %= digits;
    unsigned int y = static_cast<int>( x );

    y = ( y << n ) | ( y >> ( digits - n ) );

    return y;
}
```

Comment: Нагляднее было бы вывод все же в двоичной системе дать.

Comment: @gbg Чтобы вывести в двоичном виде, надо писать свою функцию, не так ли?

Comment: `while ( n-- ) { y = ( y << 1 ) | ( ( y & bit ) != 0 ); }`  понятно, но не оптимально.

Comment: @vlad-from-moscow Можно гадкий костыль вбить в виде конвертации в std::bitset,   а зетем из него в std::string. Зато кратко.

Comment: @gbg  Я с вами согласен. Как говорится, одна голова - хорошо, а две - лучше.:)